# Check if dayname of the date is in the dayname column data

Tags: mysql, date, mysql-error-1064, sql-date-functions

I am trying to get the where clause condition to check dayname is in the list of column data.
For example, if today is Monday and the database column has 'Monday, Tuesday', then return True.

```
ID | Days               | Action
1  | 'Monday', 'Tuesday'| Task1
2  | 'Sunday', 'Friday' | Task3
```

I am trying to get if today is Monday, then return Task 1.

```
SELECT * FROM test_table t where DAYNAME(NOW()) in (t.days)
```

The above statement is not working to get the result.

Comment: Having a comma-separated list of values in a column is almost always an indication of poor database design.

Answer (score 0):

I DO NOT recommend tou to use comma separated list to store multiple values in the DB. The right way is to normalize data and put each value into separate record in *related* table.

But *the literal solution* of your problem is to use [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)() MySQL function. It returns index of value (1-based) or 0 if str is not in strlist.
The next difficulty is that you store values enclosed in single quotes.. So, in the WHERE clause you have to escape it like

```
... WHERE FIND_IN_SET('\'Monday\'', Days)
```

Once again, I recommend you to [normalize your data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) instead.